# double login and other problems on remote desktop every 14 days

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-desktop-services

On Windows Server 2008 R2 Remote Desktop Services we got problems every 14 days on Monday morning independent of how long the server is up.

1. You have to log in twice.
2. RemoteApps will not start (only blue empty desktop)
3. no usernames in user tab of the task manager
4. USB drive redirection has malfunction

After reboot everything is fine till next Monday in two weeks. We tried to reboot the server on Friday, but it still occurred on Monday. We are not sure of the exact time the problems start. Maybe on the weekend, but we see it on Monday because no one works on weekend.

There is no planned task in task scheduler with such a trigger and we nearly deactivated all other tasks.

There is no specific error in the logs.

Restarting services like (UmRDPService, TermService, ...) has no effect.

Any idea what causes these issues?